# Powershell: Foreach Input

Tags: powershell, foreach, ram

I'm stuck on something that I know is really simple but for the life of me can't figure out.

I'm trying to import a .txt file with a list of hostnames, which once retrived, the script returns the amount of totalphysicalmemory installed.

so far I have this:

```
function get
{
$boxes = Get-Content C:\Temp\hostnamesforRAM.txt
foreach($box in $boxes)
{
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | select TotalPhysicalMemory
}
}
get
```

however, it just simply returns this:

```
4151570432
4151570432
4151570432
4151570432
4151570432
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass the current hostname ($box) to the computerName parameter, without it you're getting the value from your own computer.

```
function get
{
$boxes = Get-Content C:\Temp\hostnamesforRAM.txt
foreach($box in $boxes)
{
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $box | select TotalPhysicalMemory
}
}

get
```

Another way, more shorter, would be to pass the content of the file to the ComputerName parameter. The ComputerName parameter accepts a collection of names:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\Temp\hostnamesforRAM.txt) | 
Select-Object Name,TotalPhysicalMemory
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Shay. I tried you suggestion but it returns the error "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty"

Comment: There is a wrong iterator variable name, use `-ComputerName $box`, not `-ComputerName $_`

Comment: Thanks @akim, I was using a pipeline example!

Comment: @obious I updated my answer, give it a try now. Use $box instead of $_

Comment: I tried your shorter answer and it worked like a dream! Thanks Shay and everyone for the advice!

Answer (score 2):

This is `TotalPhysicalMemory` in bytes, to get special computer info add `computername` to command `Get-WmiObject` with proper variable name ($box in your case):

`Get-WmiObject -computername $box Win32_ComputerSystem`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
   function get
    {
    $boxes = Get-Content C:\Temp\hostnamesforRAM.txt
    foreach($box in $boxes)
    {
    "$box -> $((Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -computername $box).TotalPhysicalMemory)"
    }
    }
```